# Connecting Ditto to InfluxDB via Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, influxdb, telegraf, eclipse-ditto

I am running kafka and influxDB on docker.
I have created a digital twin on ditto, that correctly updates when i send a message with mqtt.
I want the data to be sent from ditto to the influxDB but on influxDB once i create the bucket it shows no data whatsoever.

I have followed this guide:https://www.influxdata.com/blog/getting-started-apache-kafka-influxdb/
(i know this is for a python program but the steps should be the same, i just use the telegraf plugin for kafka consumer instead of the one used in the guide).
I have created the connection and the configuration file of telegraf but nothing happens on InfluxDB.

Here is the telegraf.conf
`

```
 [[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  ## The URLs of the InfluxDB cluster nodes.
  ##
  ## Multiple URLs can be specified for a single cluster, only ONE of the
  ## urls will be written to each interval.
  ##   ex: urls = ["https://us-west-2-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com"]
  urls = ["http://localhost:8086"]

  ## API token for authentication.
  token = "$INFLUX_TOKEN"

  ## Organization is the name of the organization you wish to write to; must exist.
  organization = "digital"

  ## Destination bucket to write into.
  bucket = "arduino"

  ## The value of this tag will be used to determine the bucket.  If this
  ## tag is not set the 'bucket' option is used as the default.
  # bucket_tag = ""

  ## If true, the bucket tag will not be added to the metric.
  # exclude_bucket_tag = false

  ## Timeout for HTTP messages.
  # timeout = "5s"

  ## Additional HTTP headers
  # http_headers = {"X-Special-Header" = "Special-Value"}

  ## HTTP Proxy override, if unset values the standard proxy environment
  ## variables are consulted to determine which proxy, if any, should be used.
  # http_proxy = "http://corporate.proxy:3128"

  ## HTTP User-Agent
  # user_agent = "telegraf"

  ## Content-Encoding for write request body, can be set to "gzip" to
  ## compress body or "identity" to apply no encoding.
  # content_encoding = "gzip"

  ## Enable or disable uint support for writing uints influxdb 2.0.
  # influx_uint_support = false

  ## Optional TLS Config for use on HTTP connections.
  # tls_ca = "/etc/telegraf/ca.pem"
  # tls_cert = "/etc/telegraf/cert.pem"
  # tls_key = "/etc/telegraf/key.pem"
  ## Use TLS but skip chain & host verification
  # insecure_skip_verify = false
# Read metrics from Kafka topics
[[inputs.kafka_consumer]]
  ## Kafka brokers.
  brokers = ["localhost:9092"]

  ## Topics to consume.
  topics = ["arduino"]

  ## When set this tag will be added to all metrics with the topic as the value.
  # topic_tag = ""

  ## Optional Client id
  # client_id = "Telegraf"

  ## Set the minimal supported Kafka version.  Setting this enables the use of new
  ## Kafka features and APIs.  Must be 0.10.2.0 or greater.
  ##   ex: version = "1.1.0"
  # version = ""

  ## Optional TLS Config
  # enable_tls = false
  # tls_ca = "/etc/telegraf/ca.pem"
  # tls_cert = "/etc/telegraf/cert.pem"
  # tls_key = "/etc/telegraf/key.pem"
  ## Use TLS but skip chain & host verification
  # insecure_skip_verify = false

  ## SASL authentication credentials.  These settings should typically be used
  ## with TLS encryption enabled
  # sasl_username = "kafka"
  # sasl_password = "secret"

  ## Optional SASL:
  ## one of: OAUTHBEARER, PLAIN, SCRAM-SHA-256, SCRAM-SHA-512, GSSAPI
  ## (defaults to PLAIN)
  # sasl_mechanism = ""

  ## used if sasl_mechanism is GSSAPI (experimental)
  # sasl_gssapi_service_name = ""
  # ## One of: KRB5_USER_AUTH and KRB5_KEYTAB_AUTH
  # sasl_gssapi_auth_type = "KRB5_USER_AUTH"
  # sasl_gssapi_kerberos_config_path = "/"
  # sasl_gssapi_realm = "realm"
  # sasl_gssapi_key_tab_path = ""
  # sasl_gssapi_disable_pafxfast = false

  ## used if sasl_mechanism is OAUTHBEARER (experimental)
  # sasl_access_token = ""

  ## SASL protocol version.  When connecting to Azure EventHub set to 0.
  # sasl_version = 1

  # Disable Kafka metadata full fetch
  # metadata_full = false

  ## Name of the consumer group.
  # consumer_group = "telegraf_metrics_consumers"

  ## Compression codec represents the various compression codecs recognized by
  ## Kafka in messages.
  ##  0 : None
  ##  1 : Gzip
  ##  2 : Snappy
  ##  3 : LZ4
  ##  4 : ZSTD
  # compression_codec = 0
  ## Initial offset position; one of "oldest" or "newest".
  # offset = "oldest"

  ## Consumer group partition assignment strategy; one of "range", "roundrobin" or "sticky".
  # balance_strategy = "range"

  ## Maximum length of a message to consume, in bytes (default 0/unlimited);
  ## larger messages are dropped
  max_message_len = 1000000

  ## Maximum messages to read from the broker that have not been written by an
  ## output.  For best throughput set based on the number of metrics within
  ## each message and the size of the output's metric_batch_size.
  ##
  ## For example, if each message from the queue contains 10 metrics and the
  ## output metric_batch_size is 1000, setting this to 100 will ensure that a
  ## full batch is collected and the write is triggered immediately without
  ## waiting until the next flush_interval.
  # max_undelivered_messages = 1000

  ## Maximum amount of time the consumer should take to process messages. If
  ## the debug log prints messages from sarama about 'abandoning subscription
  ## to [topic] because consuming was taking too long', increase this value to
  ## longer than the time taken by the output plugin(s).
  ##
  ## Note that the effective timeout could be between 'max_processing_time' and
  ## '2 * max_processing_time'.
  # max_processing_time = "100ms"

  ## The default number of message bytes to fetch from the broker in each
  ## request (default 1MB). This should be larger than the majority of
  ## your messages, or else the consumer will spend a lot of time
  ## negotiating sizes and not actually consuming. Similar to the JVM's
  ## `fetch.message.max.bytes`.
  # consumer_fetch_default = "1MB"

  ## Data format to consume.
  ## Each data format has its own unique set of configuration options, read
  ## more about them here:
  ## https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/DATA_FORMATS_INPUT.md
  data_format = "json"
```

the kafka connection as it is on ditto explorer:

```
{
  "id": "0ab4b527-617f-4f4f-8bac-4ffa4b5a8471",
  "name": "Kafka 2.x",
  "connectionType": "kafka",
  "connectionStatus": "open",
  "uri": "tcp://192.168.109.74:9092",
  "sources": [
    {
      "addresses": [
        "arduino"
      ],
      "consumerCount": 1,
      "qos": 1,
      "authorizationContext": [
        "nginx:ditto"
      ],
      "enforcement": {
        "input": "{{ header:device_id }}",
        "filters": [
          "{{ entity:id }}"
        ]
      },
      "acknowledgementRequests": {
        "includes": []
      },
      "headerMapping": {},
      "payloadMapping": [
        "Ditto"
      ],
      "replyTarget": {
        "address": "theReplyTopic",
        "headerMapping": {},
        "expectedResponseTypes": [
          "response",
          "error",
          "nack"
        ],
        "enabled": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "targets": [
    {
      "address": "topic/key",
      "topics": [
        "_/_/things/twin/events",
        "_/_/things/live/messages"
      ],
      "authorizationContext": [
        "nginx:ditto"
      ],
      "headerMapping": {}
    }
  ],
  "clientCount": 1,
  "failoverEnabled": true,
  "validateCertificates": true,
  "processorPoolSize": 1,
  "specificConfig": {
    "saslMechanism": "plain",
    "bootstrapServers": "localhost:9092"
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

`the policy file for ditto:`

```
{
    "policyId": "my.test:policy1",
    "entries": {
        "owner": {
            "subjects": {
                "nginx:ditto": {
                    "type": "nginx basic auth user"
                }
            },
            "resources": {
                "thing:/": {
                    "grant": ["READ","WRITE"],
                    "revoke": []
                },
                "policy:/": {
                    "grant": ["READ","WRITE"],
                    "revoke": []
                },
                "message:/": {
                    "grant": ["READ","WRITE"],
                    "revoke": []
                }
            }
        },

        "observer": {
            "subjects": {
                "ditto:observer": {
                    "type": "observer user"
                }
            },
            "resources": {
                "thing:/features": {
                    "grant": ["READ"],
                    "revoke": []
                },
                "policy:/": {
                    "grant": ["READ"],
                    "revoke": []
                },
                "message:/": {
                    "grant": ["READ"],
                    "revoke": []
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the configuration file of telegraf but nothing happens on InfluxDB

When Telegraf is reading data from Kafka is needs to transform that into time-series metrics that InfluxDB can digest. You have correctly selected the JSON parser, but there may be additional configuraiton required, or even the use of the more powerful [json_v2 parser](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/parsers/json_v2) to be able to set the tags and fields based on the JSON data.

My suggestion is to use the `[[outputs.file]]` output to see if anything is even getting passed, probably nothing will show up. Then do the following:

1. determine what your JSON looks like in kafka
2. what you want that JSON to look like as time-series data in influxdb
3. use the [json_v2 parser](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/parsers/json_v2) to set the apporporiate tags and fields.